# How can I dynamically insert keywords into a google ad destination url

Tags: ads, google-ads-api

I have been trying to figure out a way to get my keywords into my ad destination urls dynamically. Typically I use the google url builder to generate utm params for my ads: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en

In a nutshell I am trying to dynamically populate the utm_term param in the url.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

There is the [{keyword} valuetrack parameter](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2375447?hl=en-GB) that you could use.  If you are using Google Analytics though then the easiest and quickest and least headache approach is just to link your AdWords & GA accounts then [activate auto-tagging](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1733663).